# MDX : Analysis Services 2008, Excel 2007

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, excel-2007, mdx, ssas

Using : Analysis Services 2008, Excel 2007

I've created a Cube and am able to connect from Excel.

Cube does have some Calculated Measures, Named Sets and KPIs.

Now, I'm been writing some MDX in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

How do I write MDX queries and make them available through the Cube?
Can I create Cube Views / Cube sprocs that can be visible through the Cube?

I've already got Calculated Measures, Named Sets and KPI's.

I've written some MDX, which I can run successfully through SSMS, for example as below, how would I bring this directly into the Cube as a view or sproc or something?
I would like to use this MDX through the Cube into Excel.

```
WITH
SET [2009 TO 2012] AS '{[Fiscal Year].[2009]:[Fiscal Year].[2012]}'
SELECT [2009 TO 2012] ON COLUMNS,
DESCENDANTS([Company].[Region - Country].[Region].&[EMEA]) ON ROWS 
FROM [DW]
WHERE [Date].&[2010-07-13T11:36:29]
```

thanks,
Amrit

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me correctly you cannot pass MDX into Excel (or into Office Web Components). You just have to drag-drop items onto your grid.

Google may prove me wrong though!